# Connecting Alexa to my own NodeJS back-end

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm back again with a question about NLP. I made my own back-end, which on one side can connect to websites, the Google Assistant and Facebook Messenger, and on the other end to Dialogflow. On the side, is logs interactions and does some other database stuff.

Now, I'm trying to connect this back-end to Alexa. I made a project which calls my endpoint. This project has one intent, which has a paramater which should get the raw user input, send it to my back-end, process it, parse and send the response to get back. I feel like there is not a real way to collect and send the raw user input, so I can process it myself (on Dialogflow) instead of using the Amazon way of mapping intents and such.

I know Dialogflow can export to Alexa, but this is not an option for me. I really hope one of you can point me in the right direction.

I just need a way to collect the raw user input, and respond in an Alexa accepted response format.

For Actions on Google for example, I'm using a Custom Project Action Package.

Thanks a lot in advace!

Answer (score 0):

To accept or get any user input, you can use sys.any in google assistant and AMAZON.SearchQuery in AMAZON ALEXA.

In Alexa, You have to add the carrier phrase to use AMAZON.SearchQuery. You can't combine any other slot with AMAZON.SearchQuery.

So there are also some limitations. I hope this answer will help you.